# Layout controls of a large form centered individually per each row size

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I have a form that contains a large amount of fields a user have to fill.

I want to group them 2-4 in a row. Each control may have different size and the labels should appear to the control's left.
The controls should be centered horizontally, and shouldn't take up unoccupied space, just the space needed.

Here's an example of what I need:

First Name: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓       Last name: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓      Gender: ▓▓▓▓▓

Telephone: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓     Cell: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓    Email: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓

Address: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓

I tried using `form-inline` with and without combination of `container`, and I can't get it to work.

Here's a little snippet off my form, unfortunately it's razor and I can't get to test it on jsFiddle, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shimmy/Ls6a0b4e/) is a sample output anyway.

```
<div class="container center-block">
  <h4>Patient</h4>
  <hr />
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

  <div class="row">

    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
      <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
      <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
      <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Passport, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
      <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Passport, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Passport, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
      <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's how it's rendered:
 [image]

I've tried few more things, but I don't know what's unlocking secret that makes an individual row independent in the other rows and applying the following rules to its controls, disregarding the form settings:

- Horizontal form so that each control's label is to its right
- Multiple `form-group`s per row
- Center the controls stack horizontally, not widening them to occupy all available space
- Adjust outer width according to the widest row, and then align form to left
- Have the columns inside the row be completely independent to other rows

Any reference to an in-depth tutorial will really be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the method below? If it solved the problem could you please mark it as answer? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi, I was out, sorry. I've updated my question. Someone downvoted me, probably because he knew he's anyway not gonna get those 50 I've decided to award right because I know this question does take some effort, thanks.

Comment: Never mind, I upvoted the question :) Please look at the updated code and my comments below the answer. Regarding to your questions above I strongly recommend the web pages I posted on my answer. Because there are much more than you need and you will be using at least one of them. Nevertheless, if you still a question regarding to this issue let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only part I didn't totally complete was to align the form to the left.  I think I've gotten everything else you asked for.  http://www.minimit.com/demos/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns will give you a basis for understanding centered columns.  Good luck!

Copy this to style.css in a new Plunk.

```
.row-centered {
    text-align:center;
}
.control-label{padding: 20px;}
form  { display: table;
}
h1 {
    margin:40px 40px 20px 40px;
      color:#95c500;
    font-size:28px;
    line-height:34px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Then Copy this to the Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <h1>Patient</h1>
  <div class="container" align="left">
    <form class="form-inline row-centered">

      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="" />

      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label " for="  FirstName">FirstName</label>
          <input class=" form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field FirstName must be a string with a minimum length of 2 and a maximum length of 32." data-val-length-max="32" data-val-length-min="2" data-val-required="The FirstName field is required."
          id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="  LastName">LastName</label>
          <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field LastName must be a string with a minimum length of 2 and a maximum length of 32." data-val-length-max="32" data-val-length-min="2" data-val-required="The LastName field is required."
          id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="  Gender">Gender</label>
          <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Gender field is required." id="Gender" name="Gender">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Male</option>
            <option value="1">Female</option>
          </select> <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Gender" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="  Passport">Passport</label>
          <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Passport must be a string with a minimum length of 5 and a maximum length of 12." data-val-length-max="12" data-val-length-min="5" id="Passport" name="Passport"
          type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Passport" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="  BirthDate">BirthDate</label>
          <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field BirthDate must be a date." data-val-range="The field BirthDate must be between 01/01/1915 12:00:00 AM and 01/01/2035 12:00:00 AM." data-val-range-max="01/01/2035 00:00:00"
          data-val-range-min="01/01/1915 00:00:00" data-val-required="The BirthDate field is required." id="BirthDate" name="BirthDate" type="date" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="BirthDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

[image: Here is my output:]

- Horizontal form so that each control's label is to its left: (you said left in one place and right in another).  It's easy to change.
- Multiple form-groups per row: Put your entire form into a single "row" class and let the page width responsively determine how many form groups fit.
- Center the controls stack horizontally, not widening them to occupy all available space:  See the output above, or Copy my code to a plunk and see the output there.
- Have the columns inside the row be completely independent to other rows
- Any reference to an in-depth tutorial will really be appreciated! Check out the following: http://www.minimit.com/demos/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns

Comment: Well done! Thank you so much for your great effort, you just doubled your reputation yay!

Comment: I've been learning Angular and Bootstrap for the last few months to take on an Enterprise level project.  Looking at other people's code is helping me with that process, so I'm glad I could help.  Good luck with your app.

Comment: In your HTML sample, the *Passport* and *BirthDate* `form-group`s aren't wrapped in a row. Can you please link your post to a working example, i.e. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), because I still can't get it to work. I'm using a different form than my original question where there is a top-level `div` classed as `form-horizontal`. Is there a way to override that and make current row act like a `form-inline`?

Comment: Sorry I've been in meetings the last 10 days.  I'll try to post the code soon.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at these pages below for some kind of nice designs and examples:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-5-and-css-3-the-techniques-youll-soon-be-using--net-5708

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm

http://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/index2.html

https://bootswatch.com/

http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: Still, the columns are all of the same width.
How can I have the columns' widths dependent individually per row? See desired example in my question.

Comment: I updated the code. It should be working, but let me inform after testing it. While it is possible to use different column width for each column, why do not use e fix column width? I think it seems to be much more pretty and easy to read. Is there a special reason?

Comment: I also want to center the items, please see what I've added to my question in the last bullet list. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: I updated my answer by giving some demos. I think they have answers to some of your questions. If they are not enough please check also steveo's answers below.